# how to open pdf in xmarine android?

Tags: c#, android, pdf, android-intent, android-activity

Hi am new in xmarine android,I am working in a xmarin android c# project to open a pdf file which is in the mobile internal storage "testpdf" folder. a dummy pdf file is in the "testpdf" folder. The app is asking user to choose preferred pdf viewer apps to open that pdf. but after selecting the preferred apps pdf is not showing. I have followed the below steps:

add FileProvider to the app manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="RunTimePerm.RunTimePerm" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />   
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

also created Resources\xml folder with file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-files-path name="root" path="."/>
  <external-files-path name="files" path="files" />
  <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

then added the reference Xmarin.Android.Support.V4 from NuGet.

then the following code:

```
var externalPath = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path + "/testpdf";
                Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(externalPath, "test.pdf");
                if (file.Exists())
                {
                    var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
                    try
                    {
                        Android.Net.Uri pdfPath = Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".provider", file);
                        context.GrantUriPermission(context.PackageName, pdfPath, ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                        intent.SetAction(Android.Content.Intent.ActionView);
                        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
                        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                        intent.SetDataAndType(pdfPath, "application/pdf");
                        context.StartActivity(intent);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "problem", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    }
                }
```

I have 3 options present in my mobile to open a pdf to test the scenario, i) wps office ii) Drive PDF viewer iii)Adobe Acrobat Reader.After opening wps office -- it is saying "wps office is determining the type of document" and PDF is not showing. In Drive PDF viewer-- after opening it is showing nothing. and in acrobat reader-- it is saying "file colud not be accessed. check your location" but the pdf is present in the correct location.how to resolve?

Comment: Please try this method  Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).AbsolutePath instead of global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path

Comment: Thank you for replying , I tried this method, but not working.

Answer (score 1):

got the solution,

```
try
                    {
                        string extension = MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file).ToString());
                        string mimeType = MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                        Android.Net.Uri path = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Application.Context, Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName + ".provider", file);
                        intent.SetDataAndType(path, mimeType);
                        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                        Application.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Choose App"));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "problem", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    }
```